# "non-interface type map[string]interface {} on left" error

Tags: go

I have a struct:

```
 type ListsObj struct {
    Page   string                   `json:"pages"`
    Count  string                   `json:"count"`
    Lists []map[string]interface{} `json:"assets"`
}
```

I am trying to do something like below:

```
lists := a.Lists
for _, list:= range lists{
    listData := list.(map[string]interface {})
}
```

`a` is of type `ListsObj` struct.

I am getting following error:

> invalid type assertion: list.(map[string]) (non-interface type
>   map[string]interface {} on left)

EDIT:
What I actually need to do is to call a function:

```
func WriteMapper(a interface {}) interface{}  {

}

lists := a.Lists
for _, list:= range lists{
    list = WriteMapper(list)
}
```

but this gives another error:

> cannot use WriteMapper(list) (type interface {}) as type
>   map[string]interface {} in assignment: needs type assertion

EDIT: I think I got it... the function returns `interface` and I am trying to assign that to `map[string]interface {}`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `a.Lists` (and therefore also `lists`) is a `[]map[string]interface{}`, a slice of maps. You're then iterating over that slice, and assigning the value on each iteration to the variable `list` (which is kinda oddly named, as it's holding a `map`, but that's a separate concern).

Now, `list` is of type `map[string]interface{}`. There's no need for you to type-assert it into that, since it's already that type!

To use `list` as the `map[string]interface{}` that it is, you just use it:

```
for _, list := range lists {
    someValue := list["some-key"]
    fmt.Println(someValue)
}
```

If you're trying to do something different that just using the map, I'd ask that you please clarify.